Retrieve user data infos after authentification using OAuth 2.0
How can I retrieve user data information after authentication using Django and Google OAuth2 ?
HTML
    <button>
        <a href="{% provider_login_url "google" %}">
            <div class="connexion-type">
                <div class="connexion-type-svg">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                        <!-- SVG paths -->
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="connexion-type-content">Login via Gmail</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </button>
</div>

**
Django View:**
@login_required
def redirect_google_provider(request):
    print("Access to redirect_google_provider")
    if 'code' in request.GET:
        # Extract the authorization code
        code = request.GET['code']
        
        # Debug
        print(f"Code is: {code}")

        # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
        token_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
        client_id = 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'
        client_secret = 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'
        redirect_uri = 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI'
        data = {
            'code': code,
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        }
        response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
        token_data = response.json()
        access_token = token_data.get('access_token')

        # Retrieve user information from Google API
        if access_token:
            user_info_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo'
            headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
            user_info_response = requests.get(user_info_url, headers=headers)
            user_info = user_info_response.json()
            email = user_info.get('email')

            # Check if the user exists in the system
            if email:
                user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=email, email=email)
                if created:
                    # New user, save additional information if needed
                    user.save()

                # Log the user in
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')  # Redirect to home page after successful login

    # If code is not present or user could not be logged in, redirect to login page
    return render(request, '../templates/users/login.html')

Settings.py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'redirect_google_provider'  # Redirect after authentication

Logs
[13/May/2024 05:00:17] "GET /accounts/google/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/May/2024 05:00:21] "GET /accounts/google/login/callback/?state=oirQ0xHHGNoRNQ33&code=234%2F0AdLIrYfk7gpUs678HJOjkhshdjjsJVTFpqjpAxZ4iMWttcjBzG8XhCPnijh_e_R8ntZ8jYIEsshY8ng-w&scope=profile+https%3A%2ddF%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/May/2024 05:00:21] "GET /users/redirect_google_provider HTTP/1.1" 200 15063
how to Capture
"GET /accounts/google/login/callback/?state=oirQ0xHHGNoRNQ33&code=234%2F0AdLIrYfk7gpUs678HJOjkhshdjjsJVTFpqjpAxZ4iMWttcjBzG8XhCPnijh_e_R8ntZ8jYIEsshY8ng-w&scope=profile+https%3A%2ddF%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile HTTP/1.1" 302 0


before passing it to my view ?
